# Plotting a function over surface of a cube in Octave

Tags: plot, octave

I have a function which is defined for a set of points over the surface of a cube. I know the value of the function for the coordinates. How to generate a plot which will assign a color to every point on the surface of the cube, depending on the value of the function at that point?

On 2D, I can generate colorful contour plots, but how to do something similar in 3D?

Suppose, the function which I want to plot is `f(x,y,z) = x^2 + yz`.
And, the points on the cube are defined as 
`xvar = linspace(-1,1,20)`, `yvar = linspace(-1,1,20)`, `zvar = linspace(-1,1,20)`.

Comment: look at `scatter3 (x, y, z, s, c)` where `c` is the color component

Comment: @matzeri Got it. Thanks. Please write it into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/scatter3.html This solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From:
https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/scatter3.html

> scatter3 (x, y, z, s, c)
>
> Draw a 3-D scatter plot.
>
> A marker is plotted at each point defined by the coordinates in the
>   vectors x, y, and z.
>
> The size of the markers is determined by s, which can be a scalar or a
>   vector of the same length as x, y, and z. If s is not given, or is an
>   empty matrix, then a default value of 8 points is used.
>
> The color of the markers is determined by c, which can be a string
>   defining a fixed color; a 3-element vector giving the red, green, and
>   blue components of the color; a vector of the same length as x that
>   gives a scaled index into the current colormap; or an Nx3 matrix
>   defining the RGB color of each marker individually.

If you use colors, you can try different color profiles.
`colormap(rainbow)`, `colormap(jet)` etc. These color profiles assign darker color to higher values (which the default colormap does not do), which might make the plots look better.